# What is difference between a action with HTTPPOST or without it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, http-post

```
    public ActionResult Index()
{
    return view();
    }

    [HTTPPOST]
    public ActionResult Index(){
    return view();
    }
```

what is the difference between both in ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't define any attribute above the method then Action accepts all kind requests (GET, POST etc.)

If you define `[HttpPost]` then only Post is accepted. In some cases it is very important to accept only certain kind of requests. [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/) has a good [checklist](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html#checklist) when to use Get & Post.

> Use GET if:
>
> - The interaction is more like a question (i.e., it is a
>   safe operation such as a query, read operation, or lookup).
>
> Use POST if:
>
> - The interaction is more like an order, or
> - The interaction changes the state of the resource in a way that the user would perceive (e.g.,
>   a subscription to a service),
> - or The user be held accountable for the
>   results of the interaction.

Btw. In your example there is a problem with method signatures. Method signatures must be different even if you put attributes above them.